# Migrating TimeMachine backup from USB-C flash drive to SMB mounted TimeMachine dedicated TimeMachine share

Tags: network, backup, time-machine, smb, migration

I'm looking at the following scenario.

1. On laptop with macOS 14.2.1 I've run a TimeMachine backup to a pendrive connected via USB-C
2. The backup completed and I've switched it to manual backup.

*Now I'm accessing the backup data on another drive. I wish to migrate the backup content from pendrive to a network drive.*

3. Running `ls -lah` on the said pendrive produces the following results:

   ```
   /Volumes/SANDISK
   total 8
   drwxrwxr-x@ 6 SomeUser  staff   192B 28 Dec 14:43 .
   drwxr-xr-x  8 root      wheel   256B 28 Dec 15:01 ..
   drwx------  4 SomeUser  staff   128B 28 Dec 08:39 .Spotlight-V100
   drwxr-xr-x  3 SomeUser  staff    96B 28 Dec 14:03 .com.apple.TimeMachine.IOCheck
   drwxr-xr-x@ 5 SomeUser  staff   160B 28 Dec 14:03 2023-12-28-141900.previous
   -rw-r--r--@ 1 SomeUser  staff   1.1K 28 Dec 14:43 backup_manifest.plist
   ```
4. Opening the same file in Finder shows the following content
   [image]
   Interestingly there are two backups visible but `ls` does not suggest that. I reckon that Finder/TimeMachine has a way of interpreting the `backup_manifest` files and shows content differently.
5. I'm looking to move this backup the Western Digital My Cloud Home drive that exposes the TimeMachine share via SMB ([link](https://support-en.wd.com/app/answers/detailweb/a_id/7839/%7E/steps-to-backup-a-windows-or-macos-computer-to-a-my-cloud-home))
6. The share already contains backup for another Mac
   [image]

## Questions

1. Which files from the existing USB/SANDISK backup I should move to the Network drive?
2. How can I ensure that the other laptop recognises the moved files and continues backup from that moment

Comment: To all intents & purposes, Time Machine backups on APFS are not moveable. HFS used to be. Compare the versions of this Apple KB page for Catalina & earlier to Big Sur & newer - the 'how to copy' info is gone. https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mh15137/10.15/mac/10.15 [I'm sure we already have a QA covering this, but my google-fu is failing me.]

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks for showing the interest in my question. So I reckon there is no way to address this challenge. The only other approach is to start a fresh backup on the network share from zero?

Comment: That does seem to be the case, these days.